# add apple watch app into existing project emits error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, watchos

I have objc + swift mixed project with using cocoapods. I already have bridge-header file. after i add watch app target which is companion with my app. all of my builds are failing with same message. `failed to emit precompiled header ~~~`. not only watch app scheme, every build fails

i have tried several solutions. it does not working...

here is tried solutions.

1. i checked target memebership to bridge-header, and set objc header file path to watch target's build setting.
2. add empty pod execution in pod file like this.

```
platform :ios, '13.0' # or your main app's iOS version

target 'YourMainApp' do
  # Pods for YourMainApp
  pod 'SomePodForiOS'

  target 'YourMainAppWatch' do
    platform :watchos, '6.0' # or your watch app's watchOS version
    # Pods for your watchOS app
    pod 'SomePodForWatchOS'
  end
```

3. add new bridge header file for watch app.

these this does now work.

i want to add watch app in my project... help please